# on click working on all the item together which is in iteration - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one controller and in controller i am iterating
    **ng-click="minusOne($index)"**  and  **ng-click="plusOne($index)"** but if i am clicking on first block its changing in all the iteration but i want to if i click on first block it should work on first block only

```
      .controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

            $scope.fine = [{
                likes: 0,
                dislikes: 0
            }];
            $scope.plusOne = function(index) {
                $scope.fine[index].likes += 1 * 10;
            };
            $scope.minusOne = function(index) {
                $scope.fine[index].dislikes += 1 * 10;
            };
            $scope.buildBreak = function(index) {
                $scope.fine[index].likes += 1 * 50;
            };

        }])
```

**Html**

```
<div class="item item-body addfineinfo" ng-repeat="putfine in fine">

    <a ng-click="plusOne($index)" class="button button-small button-dark">+ Fine</a>
    <a ng-click="minusOne($index)" class="button button-small button-dark">- Fine</a>
    <a ng-click="buildBreak($index)" class="button button-small button-assertive">BUILD BREAK</a>
 <input  name="message" readonly type="text" value="{{ putfine.likes - putfine.dislikes }}" placeholder="Suhr">
```

value should come in this field and this also in interation

Comment: what seems to be the problem? -> http://plnkr.co/edit/49YpzoEZHjMUWGV2zSNb?p=preview

Comment: I didnt see any issue there

Comment: Agree w/Chris ... the code seems fine. In your example above, you show only one item in the array. How are you putting multiple items in the array? The problem you describe could happen, for example, if the array was populated w/references to the same object.

Comment: sorry.. it happening only twice.. i want if i iterate 10 time it should work accordingly @chris

Comment: @supersaiyan Chris' solution should work. In fact on the surface, all of the code posted here (including your original) should work. Edit your question and show us how you are creating your array of 10 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">


<div ng-repeat="developerAdd in developer"> 
{{ developerAdd.likes}} - {{developerAdd.dislikes }}
<br/> 
<a ng-click="plusOne($index)" class="button button-small button-dark">+ Fine</a> 
<a ng-click="minusOne($index)" class="button button-small button-dark">- Fine</a> 
<a ng-click="buildBreak($index)" class="button button-small button-assertive">BUILD BREAK</a> 

</div> 
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

controller

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.developer = [{
      id: 1
  },{
      id: 2
  },{
      id: 3
  },{
      id: 4
  }];

  $scope.plusOne = function(index) {
    if ($scope.developer[index].likes == undefined) $scope.developer[index].likes = 0;
      $scope.developer[index].likes += 1 * 10;
  };

  $scope.minusOne = function(index) {
    if ($scope.developer[index].dislikes == undefined) $scope.developer[index].dislikes = 0;
      $scope.developer[index].dislikes += 1 * 10;
  };

  $scope.buildBreak = function(index) {
    if ($scope.developer[index].likes == undefined) $scope.developer[index].likes = 0;
      $scope.developer[index].likes += 1 * 50;
  };
});
```

Comment: can you create a plunker and show me what is the issue.

Comment: the plunker in above comment is fine but its working only for 2 iteration and iteration can be anything

Comment: I didnt see any issue with more than 2 items also.

Comment: i am am clicking plus or minus all the iteration reflecting on the same or can u create fiddle or plunker how ur looking the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80593/discussion-between-supersaiyan-and-simon).